# aspx radiobutton control list in one line

Tags: asp.net

http://www.codetoad.com/asp.net/aspnetcontrols11.asp

Is it possible to have radiobutton control list in one row. Now it is in 3 rows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the [`RepeatDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatdirection.aspx) and [`RepeatLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatlayout.aspx) properties of the [`RedioButtonList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) control.

There are several ways of getting the layout you want - I suggest reading the documentation of both properties in order to make an informed decision on which one is most suitable for your situation.

Answer (score 5):

In your `RadioButtonList` set the property of `RepeatLayout="Flow"` and `RepeatDirection="Horizontial"`.  This will make items in a radio button list horizontal instead of vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try adding each radio button to `<div>` or `<li>` tag and then set float:left in Css for each `<li>`. That way i think it will render in one line. Just make sure to set `width:__`  style to accommodate all radio buttons